# In cribbage, do you get points for doubles after getting to 31?

Tags: cribbage

My opponent pegged for getting to 31 by playing a jack. If I play a jack after that, do I peg for the doubles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

According to the [rules of cribbage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_cribbage):

> Card combinations cannot span a reset; once the total reaches 31 (or a Go has been scored) and counting has re-started at zero, cards already played cannot contribute to runs or pairs.

Answer (score 3):

No - cards from one round of play cannot be combined with cards from the next.

From http://www.bicyclecards.ca/game-rules/cribbage/85.php?page_id=32

> The player who called Go leads for the next series of plays, with the
>   count starting at zero. The lead may not be combined with any cards
>   previously played to form a scoring combination; the Go has
>   interrupted the sequence.